# Hyphenate "powers that be" when used as object?

Tags: hyphenation

Here's part of my sentence: `"I'm going to ask the powers that be whether[...]"`
Should it be `"I'm going to ask the powers-that-be whether[...]"`?  Bonus points for why, of course..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the hyphens.  A quick search of the internet shows the hyphenated version is quite rare and a review of the "hyphen rules" don't support the mark's use in this case.

Comment: Sounds good.  In my opinion it looks very odd without the hyphens (especially in some situations like "I will ask the powers that be to <verb>" because of the "be to <verb>."  Perhaps that is a hyphen rule exception.